# Métodos para saber como funciona un proyecto en C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Soy algo nuevo en esto de C# MVC y actualmente me han asignado un proyecto algo grande sin ningún tipo de documentación. Estoy algo desesperado y me gustaria saber como funciona, me gustaria pedirles consejo para saber que métodos o sistemas utilizáis para aprender como funciona el código (pre programado) de un proyecto en C# MVC, si el sistema de debugar linea por linea seria el mas adecuado?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwhAuW5t6dI&index=1&list=PLuEZQoW9bRnQAVxaDusY0fjRb2u7wgpzI, Les dejo el link de clases impartidas sobre MVC, y son muy buenos, explica muy bien.

Answer (score 6):

El primer paso creo que sería entender la arquitecura de una aplicacion `MVC`, o sea como aplica al patron, imagino al menos conoces que todos los request ingresan por los `controllers`, por alli es donde deberías comenzar a investigar.

Si eres muy nuevo, recomendaría tambien iniciar con un curso, los de `MVA` son muy buenos

[Introduction to ASP.NET MVC](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322)

Podrias poner breakpoint en los diferentes `actions` de los `controllers` para poder analizar por donde fluye la aplicacion a madida que navegas por las opciones en pantalla.

Conocer los `models` te daran una idea de las entidades que define la aplicacion, es importante analizarlos tambien.

No se que arquitectura implementara en la logica de negocio, si es 3 capas, si usa el patron `Repository`, o quizas si persiste usando `entity framework`. Si usa algun modelo de dominio para el negocio ayuda mucho ya que con este podras entender el modelo de negocio que define las clases, es importante identificarlo desde el principio para entender la aplicacion.

No se que version de `Visual Studio` usas, pero si es una version `Ultimate` tiene la posibilidad de generar diagramas de `Arquitectura`, como ser: diagramas de Clases, de Secuencia, Componentes, etc, esto ayuda con un analisis visual de la estructura el código.

[UML Component Diagrams: Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409393.aspx)

Comment: Hola Leandro me  han dicho que utilize un profiler como ReSharper de JetBrains es una buena opción?

Comment: ReSharper es una buena tool, pero no veo como el profiler podria ayudar, ya que este apunta a un analisis para mejorar la performance, no a entender el codigo o su estructura. un diagrama de clases, secuencia, o sea aplciar UML con las tools del VS seria mucho mas util

Comment: @gvivetapplus Lo que te comenta Leadro es lo mas adecuado y no hay mucho mas que agregar, pero si puedes agregar algo de info, sobre el proyecto, no se si solo desconozas el MVC y la parte de la persistencia de datos la domines bien, quiza ahi podriamos ayudar mas.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo primero sería tener una visión general del proyecto desde el punto de vista funcional, supongo que alguien ya te habrá explicado de que va el proyecto, como funciona y cual va a ser su evolución.

Después de esto pasaría a analizar como está estructurado el código:

- **Como está organizado el código en diferentes proyectos de Visual Studio**: podrías tener desde una estructura N-Layer (teniendo por separado las entidades de negocio, el acceso a datos, la capa de presentación, ...) hasta tener todo en el mismo proyecto. El nombre de los proyectos te debería dar una pista.
- **Como está organizado el código en cada proyecto**: cada proyecto proyecto podría tener su propia estructura agrupando las cosas en diferentes carpetas/namespaces. Por lo menos en el proyecto web tendrás elementos bien diferenciados los controladores MVC, Vistas MVC, modelos,...

Una vez que ya estás familiarizado con la estructura te va a ser mas fácil pasar a analizar el funcionamiento en profundidad.

- El **punto de partida** deberían ser los **controladores MVC** porque es donde llegan las peticiones, conforme el usuario interactúa con la aplicación. Desde ahí ir siguiendo el código (no es obligatorio depurar paso a paso, si lo haces leyendo el código irás mas rápido y depurar para terminar de entenderlo)
- Los **comentarios y documentación en el código** son tus aliados, irás viendo algún comentario y pero, sobre todo, añade los tuyos conforme vayas entendiendo como funciona *(con cabeza, que tampoco hay que llenar todo con comentarios)*
- Tu proyecto también podría incluir **pruebas unitarias/automáticas**, si es así, estás de suerte porque son de gran ayuda para entender como funciona y, sobre todo después, para ver que todo sigue funcionando cuando empiezas a realizar cambios. Y si ni las tienes, planteare ir implementándolas poco a poco.

Otras cosas  que te podían ayudar son:

- **Diagramas de la base de datos** o de entidades su usa un ORM como Entity Framework
- **Diagramas de clases**: los puedes hacer con Visual Studio, lo añades como elemento de tu proyecto y vas arrastrando las clases
- **Diagramas de relaciones/navegación y tomar notas en papel**: podrías imprimir los diagramas de clases que te has hecho antes y dibujar encima. *Esto parece rudimentario pero es rápido y siempre podrías pasarlo a limpio mas adelante*
- Capturar las consultas que se realizan a la base de datos con SQL Profiler o similar

Y por último, tener paciencia y ser consciente de que no vas a encontrar una *"herramienta mágica"* y que al principio te va a costar más hacer cualquier cambio.

**Actualización:** No hay herramientas mágicas pero si herramientas que facilitan mucho la vida. Una de ellas es [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) que permite diagnosticar muchos parámetros de tu aplicación y entre ellos, [ver las llamadas](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Views-Tab) realizadas a las vistas de MVC

Comment: Sabes si existe la posibilidad en saber que vistas estan cargadas actualmente?

Comment: Hola @gvivetapplus lo podrías tener usando Glimpse, mírate este enlace http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Views-Tab

Comment: @rsciriano excelente herramienta! por curiosidad, sabes como configurar la estación de trabajo para evitar que los archivos utilizados vayan a parar al server de desarrollo? Solamente se necesita excluirlos o hay algo extra?

Comment: @fredyfx Disculpa pero no entiendo lo que me quieres preguntar. Si es algo muy específico sobre Glimpse no se si te podré responderte porque no lo he usado personalmente, aunque no creo que tarde mucho porque me parece un proyecto muy interesante y más cuando, hace unos meses, [el equipo de desarrollo se unió a Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/07/14/the-glimpse-team-joins-microsoft/)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que tener claro que es un modelo, un controlador y una vista.

Generalmente todos los frameworks funcionan de la misma forma.

Modelo : Es una clase que define estructura y se comunica directamente con la base de datos, creando objetos y arreglos de entidades

(Juega el papel más importante)
Controlador : Es una clase en la que se pueden crear funciones. Cada función puede ser una RUTA (url) de tu proyecto.

Ejemplo

```
class UsuarioController : Controller {

  public ActionResult Inicio()
  {
      Response.Write("Página de Inicio");
  }

}
```

La ruta sería http://localhost/proyecto/usuarioController/inicio

y en ella se escribe el código de programación (llama a los modelos, llama a las vistas, realiza cálculos).

Vista: Son llamadas desde los controladores y muestran la parte visible (HTML,CSS,JS) del proyecto. Generalmente no programas en la vista, solo muestras datos o haces bucles for, foreach para mostrar la información provenida desde el controlador.

Te dejo un tutorial que explica en detalle
http://www.genbetadev.com/formacion/tutorial-de-iniciacion-en-asp-net-mvc-con-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1):

Comprendo bien tu situación hace unos años atras pase por algo semejante a ti.
Pero la verdad las respuestas que vas a conseguir ahora mismo es sugerirte aprender los conceptos básicos de MVC. pero como indicas estas desesperado.

Si tienes buen fundamento de programación puedes ir aprendiendo MVC mientras vas conociendo el proyecto y resolviendo tu problema.

Creo que Leandro Tuttini (Mas arriba)  te ha dado los primeros pasos para comenzar a debugear y explorar el proyecto (para mi es la mejor opción tienes mientras aprendes), así que no lo voy a repetir solo sigue esos pasos.

Ahora bien como ayuda extra te diré que como buena practica y normalmente un proyecto MVC tiene un controller llamado Default(o Home en otros casos) que es donde comienzan a ejecutarse los primeros actions te recomiendo que vayas alla a poner tus primeros breakpoint.

En caso de que tu proyecto use ASP.NET Identity seria muy favorable ya que esa integración ofrece mucha ayuda para ver como funciona la logica entre usuarios roles y autorizaciones por lo cual el Accounnt controller es donde tendrías que ir a poner tus breakpoint.

Utilizar ReSharper con tu conocimiento actual no sería aconsejable es un desperdicio. Mejor te recomiendo que instales en tu visual studio la extencion productivity power tools 2015.  La verdad es muy buena para maximizar la productividad pues habilita herramientas como Ctrl+Click Go to Definition, Copy As HTML, and Middle Click Scroll y muchas cosas mas, ademas de ser gratis creo que ofrece mas ayuda que el ReSharper para comenzar.

Por ultimo re recomiendo que veas este video normalmente se lo recomiendo a mis alumnos cuando quieren inicial con MVC, el video esta muy bien explicado y no es tan largo. Algo que tengo que decirte es que es en ingles, aun asi puedes habilitar la opcion de "CC" captions en el reproductor del video.

[ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamental](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

Comment: Luego de unos largos minuto formulando la respuesta me dí cuenta que este post es de unos meses atras. Para ahora el autor del post debe haber resuleto su problema pero como me tarde tanto y el post aun sigue abierto dejo mi respuesta para futuros interesados....